# How to measure the response time of a layer WMS/WFS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, wfs

Is there a way in QGIS (or pyqgis) to measure and test the response time of a WMS/WFS layer?

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly sure about the layer response time but you can log the time taken for your URL request using **requests** module in python and then use `performance.now()` to note time.